# Trying to activate an animation trigger in UNITY by a controler button press, shows multiple errors on unity, but not on compiler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an animation switch using a trigger parameter on UNITY, but even though the debugger doesn't show any bugs, unity shows me a list of errors and doesn't let me run the program.

The list of errors:
[Here is the list of errors shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FDm7.png)

How I configured the animator:
[animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UeHM.png)

The input:[button actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7ErQ.png)

The code in C#:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class SVITCH : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator Anim;

    public PlayerControls controls;

    void Awake()
    {
        Anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        controls = new PlayerControls();

        controls.Control.IdleSwitch.performed += ctx => Switcher();
        
    }

    void Switcher()
    {
        Anim.SetTrigger("sitch");

    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Control.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Control.Disable();
    }
}
```

new errors:[new Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX10a.png)

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is a keyword, therefore cannot be a class name. C# contains reserved words that have a special meaning for the compiler. These reserved words are called *keywords*. Keywords cannot be used as an identifier (name of a variable, class, interface, etc.).

Try changing it to `Switch`.

Comment: Changing the class name resolved most errors, the only one surviving is "type or namespace 'PlayerControls' could not be found

Comment: You might be missing a using directive or an assembly reference.

Comment: Get cursor over your `PlayerControls` and press show potential fixes.

Comment: it doesn't show as an error in debugger, just in the unity UI, no potential fixes appear

Comment: You will need to share the new errors but did you make the code in PlayerControls?

Comment: thge errors are there in a image that says "here are the list of errors", i made no code in Player Controls other than the automatic script.